# Array ids post to function have_post

Tags: loop, array

I get as result of a main sql an array of post IDs, now what I need that Array of ids post to obtain the information and be presented in the following way:

```
<?php
    $ids = [1,2,3,4,5];
    // Here is some execution or process
    // then I need to present the post as a normal loop
    if (  have_posts()  ) :
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
          echo get_the_title();

      endwhile; 

     endif;
     wp_reset_query();
```

How can I run the ids and then display it in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it properly,

You can use the `post__in` parameter to query for specific posts where the post ID is in that parameter:

```php
$ids = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in' => $ids,
    // ... other args, if any.
) );

// Then loop through the posts.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        // ... your code here.
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Alternatively, use `foreach` with `setup_postdata()` without having to do the `new WP_Query()`:

```php
global $post;
$ids = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    setup_postdata( $post );

    the_title();
    // ... your code here.
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```